# Adjust Height of Columns Stacked for Mobile Device (@media)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The CSS code below works great for a responsive template. It creates three columns on a desktop/laptop/iPad, and stacks those the columns for phones, etc.

BUT when viewing on a mobile device the stacked panels a are a fixed height. I need the mobile view panels to automatically lengthen when more content is added. Been trying all SORTS of different CSS solutions today, but no luck yet.

```
       * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }


       /* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

       .columntop {
          float: left;
          width: 33.33%;
          padding: 10px;
       }

       .column {
          float: left;
          width: 33.33%;
          padding: 10px;
          height: 1000px; /* This controls desktop/laptop views only */
       }

       /* Clear floats after the columns */
       .row:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
          clear: both;
       }

       /* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
       @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
         .column {
            width: 100%;
         }
       }
```

Comment: I tried that first ;-) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting that the column expending automatically? 
Have you tried height:auto?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: Good idea! Thought for sure that would work. I didn't work - bizarre. It should! I'm trying -webkit css now - maybe just a problem on iPhones? - and yes, I want the columns expanding automatically as content grows.

Comment: @BrentTruitt if so, how about check syntax? somewhere you may don't close tags or semicolon, just in case.

Comment: Thanks @VvV - will do and let you know.

Comment: are you sure you dont have conflicting commands? tryi inspecting it in the browser to see the whole list of css commands assigned to those elements